# Django NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am just starting to learn about Django and I am running into an issue. I have a modelFormSet that is meant to add 3 choices to a question you create. I have no issue when I am not using the modelFormset and only adding one question but when I try to iterate through a modelsFormset and assign each choice to the question that was just created I get the following error:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: polls_choice.question_id
```

I think it has something to do with the question_id not being passed to the choice model but I am not sure how to fix it. I have run fresh migrations and I don't think I can set blank or null to True since I need the choice and question to be related. Thank you in advance for your help!

Models

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Forms

```
class CreateQuestion(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question_text', 'assigned_to', 'pub_date',)


class AddChoices(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ('choice_text',)
```

View

```
def create_question(request):
    choices_formset = modelformset_factory(Choice, form=AddChoices, fields=('choice_text',), extra=3)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        question_form = CreateQuestion(data=request.POST)
        choice_form = choices_formset(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if question_form.is_valid and choice_form.is_valid:
            question = question_form.save()
            for choice in choice_form:
                choice.question = question
                choice.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:index'))
        else:
            return render(request, 'polls/createquestion.html', {'question_form': question_form,
                                                                 'choice_form': choice_form, })
    else:
        question_form = CreateQuestion()
        choice_form = choices_formset(queryset=Choice.objects.none(),)
        return render(request, 'polls/createquestion.html', {'question_form': question_form,
                                                             'choice_form': choice_form, })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you loop through `for choice in choice_form`, each item is a form, so setting the `question` attribute doesn't work.

Instead, you should save with `commit=False`, set the question, then save the object to the db.

```
for form in choice_form:
    choice = form.save(commit=False)
    choice.question = question
    choice.save()
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
            for choice in choice_form:
                choice.question = question
                choice.save()
```

You're iterating here over `AddChoices` forms, not over `Choice` objects. That mean, you're saving question as an attribute of form, not as attribute of model instance and that won't propagate into model instance.

To fix it you can try:

```
            for form in choice_form:
                choice = form.save(commit=False)
                choice.question = question
                choice.save()
```